# Javascript es6 class inheritance

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

Can someone please explain to me why calling a parent function from child is reseting parent class variables.

```
class Garages {
    constructor() {
        this.garages = {};
    }

    addGarage(id) {
        this.garages[id] = {id};
        return this.garages[id];
    }

    getGarage(id) {
        alert(this.garages[id]); //why undefined?
    }
}

class Cars extends Garages {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.cars = [];
    }

    getGarageByID(id) {
        this.getGarage(id)
    }
}

const cars = new Cars();
const garages = new Garages();

console.log(garages.addGarage("one"))
cars.getGarageByID("one")
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/02qzve6t/10/)

Comment: `getGarageByID` doesn't return anything. (`addGarage` does)

Comment: *"alerts undefined because this.garages is empty object"* – Nope, alerts `undefined` because you're not `return`ing anything from `Cars.getGarageByID`.

Comment: @deceze that's not it. `cars` and `garages` are unrelated instances. Even returning something doesn't help here.

Comment: @Mark Yes, that too. Was about to comment on it. I'm spewing out errors as I see them, like any proper compiler does. ;)

Comment: The class structure doesn't really make sense. A `car` is not a kind of `garage`. A better arrangement might be for `Garages` instances to have an array of `Cars`.

Comment: The structure is just an example. The problem is not why it does not return anything, the problem is why this.garages is empty. Please see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/02qzve6t/10/

Comment: @KhawerZeshan Your specific `const cars` and `const garages` are in no way associated with one another.

Comment: `this.garages` of `cars` is empty because it's not the same `this.garages` as the one of `garages`. They're different objects! Inheritance has nothing much to do with it.

Comment: `getGarageByID` is calling `getGarage` of Garages class, shouldn't `this` in the Garages class refer to its class `this`?

Comment: Forget about inheritance. You could squash both classes into the same class for the same end result. You're constructing two different objects, and anything on `this` just exists on that object instance. How you expect it to work is simply not how inheritance works or how it's supposed to be used.

Comment: `cars ` and `garages` are two different objects. They share nothing with each other. Inside `garages.addGarage`, `this` refers to `garages`. Inside `cars.getGarageByID`, `this` refers to `cars`.

Answer (score 3):

beacuse the instance of cars is differnet from garages , you should write like this:

```
 alert(cars.addGarage("one")) //alerts object
 alert(cars.getGarageByID("one"))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Issue #1** is that you are adding to one instance and asking another to get you the value.

**Issue #2** is that you are not returning anything from `getGarageByID` hence you get `undefined`.

Change your code to this:

```js
class Garages {
    constructor() {
        this.garages = {};
    }
    addGarage(id) {
        this.garages[id] = {id};
        return this.garages[id];
    }
    getGarage(id) {
        return this.garages[id];
    }
}

class Cars extends Garages {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.cars = [];
    }
    getGarageByID(id) {
        return this.getGarage(id)
    }
}

const cars = new Cars();

console.log(cars.addGarage("one"))
console.log(cars.getGarageByID("one"))
```

And you should get both to print.